# Distance matrix for pairwise comparisons between two different vectors

Tags: r, distance

I am trying to compute a distance matrix between every pairwise comparison for vector j and vector k. I encountered one [stack overflow post related to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654227/r-distance-matrix-build-from-two-vectors-n-1) but it compares each row of j to the corresponding row of k. However, I want to compare each row of j to every row of k and so on... Just like the dist() function in R will accomplish with one vector, however with two vectors.

For example, dist() will take a vector of 100 units and return a lower triangle with 4950 comparisons/distances. I would like to achieve this except with a vector j of 100 units and a vector k of 100 units and compare each of j to each of k.

A smaller example:

```
set.seed(5)
a<-rnorm(5)
b<-rnorm(5)
cbind(a,b)
               a          b
[1,] -0.84085548 -0.6029080
[2,]  1.38435934 -0.4721664
[3,] -1.25549186 -0.6353713
[4,]  0.07014277 -0.2857736
[5,]  1.71144087  0.1381082
```

I would like to compare 1a to 1b, 2b, 3b, 4b, and 5b. Then, 2a to 1b, 2b, 3b, 4b, 5b. etc. Just like dist() except instead of a distance matrix with itself, a distance matrix with a different vector.

Does anyone know what the best way to accomplish this might be?

EDIT: In addition to Joel's great tidyverse answer, I figured out a sort of base R workaround to doing this...

If you have a vector A of 100 items and a vector B of 100 items, you can concatenate a vector of A followed by B, use dist and then index only the columns and rows that comparisons between the two concatenated vectors:

```
distM<-as.matrix(dist(c(A, B)))
distM<-as.matrix(distM[-(1:100),-(101:200)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were solving this problem I would use the `crossing()` fucntion to create a list of all of the comparisons and then calculate using the `mutate()` function all the distances.

This would be using functions from the tidyverse library atop base r. Let me know if you need a base r solution and I will have a rethink.

```r
# Imports
library(tidyverse)

# Data construction
set.seed(5)
a<-rnorm(5)
b<-rnorm(5)

# Create all pairwise comparisons
pairs <- crossing(a, b)

# Calculate the distances
pairs %>% 
  mutate(dist = abs(a - b))
#> # A tibble: 25 x 3
#>         a      b  dist
#>     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 -1.26  -0.635 0.620
#>  2 -1.26  -0.603 0.653
#>  3 -1.26  -0.472 0.783
#>  4 -1.26  -0.286 0.970
#>  5 -1.26   0.138 1.39 
#>  6 -0.841 -0.635 0.205
#>  7 -0.841 -0.603 0.238
#>  8 -0.841 -0.472 0.369
#>  9 -0.841 -0.286 0.555
#> 10 -0.841  0.138 0.979
#> # ... with 15 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>